# Convert a Java string into 16-byte byte array

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a limitted storage that can only stores 16 bytes in byte array.  If I have a long string, the String.getBytes() will not work for me.

How would you do to convert/encode a long java string in 7-bit standard ascii characters set into 16-byte byte array, that can be encoded back to original string?  Still, I understand there will be limtation to the original input string. I am also looking for advise how to set the requirements with reasonable lengh limitations, i.e., email address length.

Comment: Does the string have an arbitrary value, or are there only a limited number of values it can have? How many of these strings will there be? Is the storage limited to RAM, or is it possible to store strings somewhere where the 16 byte limit is lifted?

Comment: The limitation actually is set by an external lib that is limits to take byte array in 16 fixed array size.  My input strings are actually email address in 7-bit ascii printable characters sets. I cannot limit the email address to be less than 16 chars, but I would like to know a reasonable way to extend to reasonable email length.

Comment: If it's email addresses, it's easy to create a custom encoding that maps all lowercase and most punctuation to 5-bit characters, then extend it to add support for digits. This way, you can fit max 25 characters in 16 bytes. Not sure it it's enough for you though. For me, it's not. You can also do some experiments with encoding addresses using contextual Huffman coding. I doubt the results will be great though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking is impossible. An arbitrary, sufficiently long and complex string cannot be encoded in 16 bytes.

Even if the string only uses 7-bit standard ASCII characters, you would be limited to encoding/decoding strings with 18 characters ((8 bits per byte * 16 bytes) / 7 bits per character). The actual bit shifting arithmetic in this case would be very messy, and the resulting memory savings would be negligible.

Comment: My bad quesiton to start with. Obviously this is technical impossible without reasonable limitation on the input string. Let me rework my question.  Thanks.